# Getting the biggest connected component in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

How do I get a subgraph of the the biggest component of a graph?

Say for example I have a graph `g`.

```
size_components_g <-clusters(g, mode="weak")$csize
size_components_g
#1 2 3 10 25 2 2 1

max_size <- max(size_components_g)
max_size
#25
```

So 25 is the biggest size.

I want to extract the component that has these 25 vertices. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, detailed explanation of output value of any function in the R package could be found in its documentation. In this case `igraph::clusters` returns a named list where in `csize` sizes of clusters are  stored while `membership`  contains the cluster id to which each vertex belongs to.

```
g <- igraph::sample_gnp(20, 1/20)

components <- igraph::clusters(g, mode="weak")
biggest_cluster_id <- which.max(components$csize)

# ids
vert_ids <- V(g)[components$membership == biggest_cluster_id]

# subgraph
igraph::induced_subgraph(g, vert_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks Krashov. I had actually tried with  csize and membership. But did not know how to put them together. You have used which.max(components$csize). That was truly helpful.